# Get timestamp from Ansible control server and add it to a command run on remote system

Tags: variables, ansible, timestamp, localhost

I am running Ansible playbooks from a Linux server, and connecting to remote network appliances. I have a playbook to archive the configuration of the remote applaince, in a storage location on the appliance itself. It is basically a 'copy running-config {{ filename }}' job.  How can I grab the timestamp from the control server before I run the remote command?  Basically I want to store the control server's timestamp in a variable and then summon the variable when I run the remote archive command.

Answer (score 1):

`ansible_date_time` is a fact available on any machine where you have gathered facts.

```
$ ansible localhost -m setup -a filter=ansible_date_time
localhost | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_date_time": {
            "date": "2020-01-24",
            "day": "24",
            "epoch": "1579835473",
            "hour": "04",
            "iso8601": "2020-01-24T03:11:13Z",
            "iso8601_basic": "20200124T041113893686",
            "iso8601_basic_short": "20200124T041113",
            "iso8601_micro": "2020-01-24T03:11:13.893763Z",
            "minute": "11",
            "month": "01",
            "second": "13",
            "time": "04:11:13",
            "tz": "CET",
            "tz_offset": "+0100",
            "weekday": "vendredi",
            "weekday_number": "5",
            "weeknumber": "03",
            "year": "2020"
        }
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

Let's say `epoch` is your choice for timestamp, you can access it in any jinja2 templated string with `ansible_date_time.epoch`.

```
- name: My timestamp play
  hosts: my_hosts
  tasks:
    - name: Show timestamp
      debug:
        msg: "Epoch on {{ inventory_hostname }} is {{ ansible_date_time.epoch }}"
```

This will contain the fact for your target machine, i.e. the date and time info of your target at time when the facts were gathered.

If you really want the date time info from your local host, you will need to make sure you have gathered the facts from `localhost`. A simple empty play targeting `localhost` like below is enough  and you can then use `hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time.epoch`

```
- name: Make sure we have localhost facts
  hosts: localhost

- name: Rest of my playbook
  hosts: my_hosts
  tasks:
    - name: Show timestamp from localhost for each target machine
      debug:
        msg: >-
          ansible contoler's epoch is
          {{ hostvars['localhost'].ansible_date_time.epoch }}
          (displayed from {{ inventory_hostname }})
```